# How to click(using js) on element selectized with selectize.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, selectize.js

We are using selectize.js to make select tags on our page. The problem with it is that there are made(those divs with options) when you click on select input so there are not in DOM after page load.

What I need is to click (using javascript) on specified option after page load, but what I tried did nothing. (I want to pre-fill form when someone enters the page)

Here's some code I've tried:

```
$('.selectize-input').first().click()
$("div[data-value='#{ob['shipping']['country_label']}']").first().click()

# --------------------
$('.selectize-input').first().click()
  $('.selectize-dropdown').first().bind 'afterShow', ->
    $(document).on 'click', "div[data-value='#{ob['shipping']['country_label']}']", ->
      @.click()
# --------------------
```

(but `@` in `@.click()` actually means `selectize-dropdown`?)

I've also tried populate all needed inputs, but it didn't work neither.

```
  $('.selectize-dropdown').first().click()
  $('.selectize-dropdown-content').first().click()
  $('.selectize-dropdown-content .option').each (idx, el) ->
    if $(el).text() == "#{ob['shipping']['country']}"
      $(el).addClass('selected')
      return true;
    else
      $(el).removeClass('selected')

  $('#shipping_detail_shipping_country option').first().val(ob['shipping']['country_label']).text(ob['shipping']['country'])
  $('.selectize-input .item').data('value', ob['shipping']['country_label']).text(ob['shipping']['country'])
```

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**

```
<div class="selectize-control single">
   <div class="selectize-input items required not-full has-options"
     <input style="width: 41px; opacity: 1; position: relative; left: 0px;" placeholder="Kraj..." tabindex="" autocomplete="off" type="text">
   </div>
     <div style="display: none; width: 1158px; top: 52px; left: 0px; visibility: visible;" class="selectize-dropdown single">
      <div class="selectize-dropdown-content"><div data-group="Europa" class="optgroup">
        <div class="optgroup-header">Europa</div>
        <div data-value="AL" data-selectable="" class="option">Albania</div><div data-value="AD" data-selectable="" class="option">Andora</div>
...
```

This is my select tag.

This is my coffee:

```
$('.selectize-input').first().click()
$('.selectize-control').on 'click', "div.option", =>
  console.log("AA")
  console.log(@)
  $("div[data-value='#{ob['shipping']['country_label']}']").click()
```

(My bad with the indentation, in .coffee file it is correct)
First line open select list, but rest do nothing. Nothing in console, nothing on page. Am I missing something?

Comment: You're asking how to attach listeners to dynamically created elements?

Comment: Well, I found that I could use .on() event but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Then there's a problem with your selector. `.on('event', element, handler)` works even for dynamically added elements.

Comment: Can I call `element.click()` in `handler` and it still can work? Or do I need to do it another way?

Comment: You lose the `this` (@) value in a handler unless you bind it. Use a fat arrow `=>` function instead of a skinny `->`.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. Coffeescript is whitespace sensitive. Also, it looks like you are trying to trigger the click *before* you attach the handler? `.on` handlers work no matter what, I generally move those as high in the source as I can...

Comment: Thanks for your time and advices, but it didn't quite work for me.
Now I try to do it with setting default value when selectizing(it's more appropriate way?)

Comment: I realize my comments may seem nitpicky, but you have a mistake in your html your second div the tag isn't closed, you can tell from the syntax highlighting being off. Which makes it hard to know if that's part of the problem. Nor is it clear why you can't just but the `selected` attribute on the `option` you want pre-selected, that's easy to do even if you're defining the tags dynamically in JavaScript.

Comment: Well, it may be my fault, when I copied it from actual code from page.
Finally, I've come up with using `.setValue()` from selectize.js methods and it worked.
Thanks again :)